# insert dictionary in a list of nested objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following JSON data:

```
[{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key": 1, "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": [{"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}]}, "status_txt": "OK"},{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key": 1, "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": []}, "status_txt": "OK"}]
```

I need to append a list of dictionaries: `{"key":"a"},{"key":"b"}`

in a way each key is added in every object so the result can be like this:

```
[{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key": 1, "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": [{"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}]}, "status_txt": "OK", "key":"a"},{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key": 1, "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": []}, "status_txt": "OK", "key":"b"}]
```

One of the answers I tried was this code but it is not working:

```
data = json.load(open('file.json'))
if type(data) is dict:
   data = [data]

data.append({"key": "a","key": "b"})
with open('file.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Error: `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 449 (char 448)`

Is this possible?
Thank you!

Comment: I doubt you even tried something since your JSON is not correct.

Comment: @IMCoins : Sorry, I just modified it.

Comment: That wasn't my point unfortunately. But that's good if you corrected it. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Well I have been spending the last couple of days on this, do I have to list all what I did to be answered?

Comment: It just shows that you tried and not just come here for some fast answers to a problem you have. :)

Comment: @IMCoins I wrote the last code I tried but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between **dict** and **list**.

As far as I understand your problem, with the input you provided, your data and output, you can do :

```
inp = [{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key": 1, "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": [{"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}]}, "status_txt": "OK"},{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key": 1, "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": []}, "status_txt": "OK"}]
data = [{"key":"a"},{"key":"b"}]
out = [{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key": 1, "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": [{"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}, {"key": "value", "key": "value"}]}, "status_txt": "OK", "key":"a"},{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key": 1, "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": []}, "status_txt": "OK", "key":"b"}]

for item, data_item in zip(inp, data):
    item.update(data_item)

print( inp == out )
# True
```

What you are doing in this code is : since your data is a list of the same length than your input, and want to add the first item of your data, to the first item of your input...

- You want to iterate through your data at the same time than your input. The `zip()` takes care of that by basically making a tuple of each elements in both your list. `zip([1, 2], [3, 4])` becomes `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]`.
- Then, at each iteration, **update** your dictionnary input with the dictionnary data.

As you can see, it gives True if I compare it to the output you said you wanted. :)